# In a "simple" cubic integer ring, does the sign of the number always match the sign of the norm?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Inspired by this question: [Need the norm of positive number be positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163117/need-the-norm-of-positive-number-be-positive) The "Best Answer" for that question gives as examples six cubic rings that will perhaps be forever beyond my ability to comprehend.

Given $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, cubefree, not a perfect square, consider the ring $\mathcal{O}$ of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\root 3 \of d)$. Is "simple" the appropriate terminology for such a ring? If it's not, you'll let me know (and how!).

A number $x \in \mathcal{O}$ is real, and if $x \neq 0$, we can say $x < 0$ or $x > 0$. Likewise, $N(x) < 0$ or $N(x) > 0$. It seems like $\textrm{sgn}(x) = \textrm{sgn}(N(x))$ always.

From this other question [What is the norm of a number in a cubic integer ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163995/what-is-the-norm-of-a-number-in-a-cubic-integer-ring) I see that $N(a + b \root 3 \of d + c \root 3 \of {d^2}) = a^3 + b^3 d + c^3 d^2 - 3abcd$ ($a, b, c$ are integers, or at least rational, depending on $d$).

I have played around with some primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\root 3 \of 2]$, $\mathbb{Z}[\root 3 \of 3]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\root 3 \of 5]$, reasoning that if $x$ is a product of two primes exhibiting $\textrm{sgn}(x) \neq \textrm{sgn}(N(x))$, only one of the prime factors also shows this sign disagreement. (I would settle for irreducible numbers, but I've so far only looked at UFDs.)

On further reflection, I could be wrong on that last point, and in any case it might be easier to find a "composite" number exhibiting the sign disagreement.

My main question here is: in a cubic ring as described above, for which the norm of a number can be readily calculated by plugging $a, b, c$ in the formula given above, does the sign of a number always match the sign of the norm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cubic field of the form $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt [3]d)$ is usually called "pure". Its ring of integers is generally not $\mathbf Z[\sqrt [3]d]$, there are two cases depending on whether $d \equiv \pm 1$ mod $9$ or not (see e.g. Marcus' "Number Fields", end of chapter 2). But since your question is simply about signs, why bother with integers, we just have to work in the field $K$ itself. Since $3=1+2$, the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbf C$ are exactly the three which are determined by $Id: \sqrt [3]d \to \sqrt [3]d$ , $\sigma: \sqrt [3]d \to j \sqrt [3]d$, $\tau: \sqrt [3]d \to j^2 \sqrt [3]d$, where $j$ denotes a primitive 3rd root of unity. The norm of any $x \in K$ is given by $N(x)=x.\sigma (x) .\tau (x)$. But by definition, $\sigma (x)$ and $\tau (x)$ are complex conjugates, hence their product is just the square of the module of $ \sigma (x)$, which shows that $x$ and $N(x)$ have the same sign.

Note that the above argument carries over to arbitrary cubic fields which are not totally real, plainly because $3=1+2$. Note also that it is not fundamentally different from @Will Jagy, except that we avoided to express explicitly the quotient $N(x)/x$, which allowed us not to appeal to the theory of ternary quadratic forms.

Comment: Looks good, but, if we assume that KCd's answer to one of the linked questions is correct, wouldn't that mean your second paragraph is at least partially incorrect?

Comment: To add on to @Robert's comment above, this argument carries over to cubic fields which are not totally real. The statement is false in totally real cubic fields, as KCd's answer shows.

Comment: You are right, the argument does not carry on to totally real fields. I edit the beginning of my second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming $d > 0$ and  $\omega^3 = d,$ so that also $d \omega = \omega^4$ for example.

$$ \left( a + b \omega + c \omega^2 \right) \left( a^2 + b^2 \omega^2 + c^2 d \omega - bcd - ca \omega^2 - ab \omega \right) = a^3 + b^3 d + c^3 d^2 - 3abcd $$
so we just need to show, using $\omega$ real, that the quadratic form is positive.  Better to write
$$ a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 -bcyz - ca zx - ab xy.  $$
We do find $a^2$ and binary $a^2 x^2 -abxy + b^2 y^2$ positive. The discriminant (Watson and Lehman) is
$$ \Delta = 4 a^2 b^2 c^2 +(bccaab) - a^2b^2 c^2 - b^2c^2 a^2 - c^2a^2 b^2, $$
$$ \Delta = 2 a^2 b^2 c^2.$$
So this is a positive definite form, take
$$ x=1, \; \; y = \omega, \; \; z = \omega^2  $$ in
$$ a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 -bcyz - ca zx - ab xy  $$
to show
$$ a^2 + b^2 \omega^2 + c^2 d \omega - bcd - ca \omega^2 - ab \omega > 0.  $$

I see how to factor the quadratic form. We will need 
$$ \sigma \neq 1, \; \;  \sigma^3 = 1, $$ so that
$$ \sigma^2 + \sigma = -1, $$
$$ \sigma^2 + \sigma^4 = -1. $$ Then
$$ \left( a + b \omega \sigma + c \omega^2 \sigma^2 \right) \left( a + b \omega \sigma^2 + c \omega^2 \sigma \right) = a^2 + b^2 \omega^2 + c^2 d \omega - bcd - ca \omega^2 - ab \omega$$
Since we also have
$$  \sigma^2 = \bar{\sigma},$$
our quadratic form is the product of complex conjugates and positive for that reason.